# Multiple Points showing up for for a given date after applying a Savitzky–Golay filter to smooth my data

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat, smoothing

I've been trying to draw NIR and NDVI data from LANDSAT and SENTINEL-1 data respectively, which can often be a little noisy. As such, I've been trying to apply the Savitzky–Golay filter available at:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2

In general, the smoother works. However, at some dates it generates two point of different values on the same date, and I'm not sure why. It seems to have drastic effects on the smoothing of the data, and I was wondering if anyone had any clue why this may be happening and/or a fix for it. My current code is available at:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0142de87f5ee0fd77c21a38a30a974ea

Comment: Please update the question with the code, not just the link to the code. Also, you mention applying the Savitzky-Golay filter but your code doesn't do this at all. Do you mean that this is applied in the ui.Chart? can you show a reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Landsat image collection consists of images from different path/rows. In some dates, there are images from two different path/rows, although not exactly at the same `system:time_start`. For example,

`LC08_043034_20170420` has a `system:time_start` of `1492713557772`, corresponding to `2017-04-20T11:39:17` (America/Los_Angeles local time)

but you also have:

`LC08_043035_20170420` with a `system:time_start` of `1492713581659`, corresponding to `2017-04-20T11:39:41` (America/Los_Angeles local time)

The `ui.Chart` includes them both because they are two different observations.

If you want to reduce your time series so that at any given date you have only one observation, then you have to do it prior to sending the data to the chart.

First, we can set set a "date" property that only cares about year, month, and date, but not hour, minutes, seconds:

```js
.map(function(img){
  return img.set({"date":ee.Number(img.date().update(null,null,null,0,0,0).millis())})
})
```

Then you have the option to simply discard duplicates based on "date":

```js
.distinct("date")
```

For example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2b15c1ac2f93f7f5a86cf36bb48924f1

here we see that for the April 20 date, it shows only the value from `LC08_043034_20170420` (0.268 for `SR_B5`).

You might be tempted to use a combination of both images (e.g. the mean value), instead of simply discarding one, which is fair. It's possible, but it complicates things:

We can reduce each image collection for a given date:

```js
function reduceByDate(date){
  return dataset
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq("date",date))
  .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
  .setDefaultProjection("EPSG:32610",null,30)
  .set({"system:time_start":date})
}

var datasetReducedByDate = ee.ImageCollection(
  dataset
  .aggregate_array("date")
  .distinct()
  .map(reduceByDate)
)
```

This new image collection has different band names (e.g. "SR_B5_mean"), which you can rename.. but we also lose the original projections and other properties. If you don't set a defaultProjection for this new image collection, you will get the following error in the Chart:

> Error generating chart: Collection.first: Error in map(ID=0): Image.reduceRegion: The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform.

So now you have to take care of specifying the projection for your new image collection (e.g. above I defined a single one for all images), and you also have to add the `system:time_start` property explicitly.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e629942943a9c0391e509d9fb0bfded3

Here we can see that we get a value of 0.264 for April 20, 2017 (mean of 0.268 and 0.260).